# Unicode for English and French strings in Android

Tags: android, unicode

I have to encode English and French using UTF-8 or UTF-16. I have no clear idea which one to use in which case. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html), by [Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/AboutMe.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use UTF-8 for both languages because it contains encodings for all the special French characters. See this link: [UNICODE UTF-8 ENCODING](http://www.periodni.com/unicode_utf-8_encoding.html#french_special_characters)